# How to flatten entities for display in a table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Given EF entities defined as follows

```
class Person { int PersonID; string Name; string Title; }
class ContactType { int TypeID; string TypeString; } // phone # types - mobile, home, work etc.
class PersonContact { int PersonID, int ContactTypeID, string ContactText; bool IsDefault; }
```

Where a person can have multiple phone #'s and even multiple mobile #'s

Looking for ways to display all Persons in a table structure as follows

```
PersonID, Name, Title, PrimaryContact, MobileNumber
```

Where PrimaryContact is the PersonContact Record with IsDefault = true

and

WHERE MobileNumber is "A" PersonContact Record with PersonContact.ContactType = ContactType.TypeID and ContactType.TypeString = "Mobile"

NOTE -

PrimaryContact is a lookup into PersonContact

MobileNumber is ALSO a lookup into PersonContact

They could point to the same PersonContact record or could be different depending on IsDefault = true

ALSO There could be multiple "Mobile" PersonContact records for a person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below.

```
var result = ctx.Persons
.Select(x => 
new {PersonID = x.PersonID, 
     Name = x.Name,
     Title = x.Title,
     PrimaryContact = x.PersonContacts.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsDefault == true).Select(t => t.ContactText),
     MobileNumber = x.PersonContacts.FirstOrDefault(z => z.ContactType.TypeString =="Mobile").Select(q => q.ContactText)
     }).ToList();
```

Sadly i think this might result in a select n + 1 type query :(

Comment: PrimaryContact & MobileNumber could be two difference records in PersonContact table

Comment: @Kumar your question doesn't clearly show the relationship .. could you show it please? it will help me provide a better answer

Comment: updated Q, hope it is clearer now, essentially there could be multiple mobile phone #'s for a person, only one of which could have IsDefault = true set which would show up in the PrimaryContact OR IsDefault = true could be set for a work phone # in which case PrimaryContact and MobileNumber would show different #'s in the flattened table

Comment: Any way to select all  fields in Person if there are say 20 additional fields in that entity/table ?